# Visual Studio professional 2017-c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I downloaded Visual Studio professional 2017 from the Microsoft website and installed the universal windows platform development.
I wanted to open a new c# project, but there were no options to console application, Windows Form, and a lot of others.
Which pack do I need to install from the Visual Studio installer?

Comment: from personal experience: I also wanted to be a special snowflake and tried to install only the packages *i need*. That turned out to be a major headache, so my advice: install all (or at leas the default ones) if you have the option(space)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run the installer again and do "Modify" and make sure ".NET Desktop Development" is enabled to get Windows Form application project types you can also install "ASP.NET and Web Development" for web stuff or any others you might need, if have space + time install them all, if needed, but should only need to install the things you need.